# Recursion in MIPS with arrays

Tags: recursion, mips, mars-simulator

I'm a beginner user of MARS for programming in MIPS language. I started to study the recursion and I wrote a little method in java that take in input an array and an index, and make a recursive sum of all its elements. But I don't know how to write it in mips language, someone can help me?

```java
public int recursiveSum(int i, int[] array)
{
    if(i == array.length-1)
        return array[i];
    return array[i]+recursiveSum(i+1, array);
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the MIPS instruction set? Do you understand what it means for a function to recur, and how a stack works? If not, you should start by studying those things. If you are familiar with them already, then start writing the assembly code and explain in your question exactly what part of the code it is that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a recursive function in `mips`, you need to save the return address (register `$ra`) on a stack frame you create for the function call's duration, restoring it upon exit (and removing/popping the frame).

Simple functions can get by minimally with just the save/restore of `$ra`, but, for recursive functions they typically have to save/restore some of their arguments as well.

Aside from the mips instruction set reference, one of the things you'll want to consult is the mips ABI document as it lays out which registers get used in which context for which purpose. This is particularly important when writing recursive code.

Here's a program that implements your function with unit tests. It has two different recursive function implementations to help illustrate some of the tricks you do [can do] in asm.

Notice in the top comment block your original function and a modified one that removes the "non-standard" return statement. That is, when using a high level language as pseudo-code for asm, just have a *single* return statement as that's how the asm gets implemented. It's important to keep things simple in the HLL. The simpler it is, the more literal the translation to the asm.

Also, there are some things you can do in asm [mips in particular] that can't be done/modeled in an HLL. mips has 32 registers. Imagine putting invariant values [such as the address of your array] in "global" registers that are preserved across all calls. The address is in a *register* and not on the stack or global *memory*, so it's *very* fast.

There is no HLL equivalent for this. BTW, if you know `C`, I'd do the pseudo-code in that rather than `java`. `C` has pointers [and explicit memory addresses], whereas `java` does not, and pointers are the lifeblood of asm.

Anyway, here's the code. It is well annotated, so, hopefully, it's easy to read:

```
# recursive sum
#
#@+
# // original function:
# public int recursiveSum(int i, int[] array)
# {
#
#     if (i == (array.length - 1))
#         return array[i];
#
#     return array[i] + recursiveSum(i + 1,array);
# }
#
# // function as it could be implemented:
# public int recursiveSum(int i, int[] array)
# {
#     int ret;
#
#     if (i == (array.length - 1))
#         ret = 0;
#     else
#         ret = recursiveSum(i + 1,array);
#
#     return array[i] + ret;
# }
#
# // function as it _was_ be implemented:
# public int[] array; // in a global register
#
# public int recursiveSum(int i)
# {
#     int ret;
#
#     if (i == (array.length - 1))
#         ret = 0;
#     else
#         ret = recursiveSum(i + 1);
#
#     return array[i] + ret;
# }
#@-

    .data

sdata:

array:
    .word   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    .word   11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
    .word   11,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30

arrend:

msg_simple: .asciiz     "simple sum is: "
msg_recur1: .asciiz     "recursive sum (method 1) is: "
msg_recur2: .asciiz     "recursive sum (method 2) is: "
msg_match:  .asciiz     "difference is: "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"
    .text
    .globl  main

# main -- main program
#
# registers:
#   s0 -- array count (i.e. number of integers/words)
#   s1 -- array pointer
#   s2 -- array count - 1
#
#   s3 -- simple sum
#   s4 -- recursive sum
main:
    la      $s1,array               # get array address
    la      $s0,arrend              # get address of array end
    subu    $s0,$s0,$s1             # get byte length of array
    srl     $s0,$s0,2               # count = len / 4
    subi    $s2,$s0,1               # save count - 1

    # get simple sum for reference
    jal     sumsimple               # get simple sum
    move    $s3,$v0                 # save for compare

    # show the simple sum results
    la      $a0,msg_simple
    move    $a1,$v0
    jal     showsum

    # get recursive sum (method 1)
    li      $a0,0                   # i = 0
    jal     sumrecurs1              # get recursive sum
    move    $s4,$v0                 # save for compare

    # show the recursive sum results
    la      $a0,msg_recur1
    move    $a1,$v0
    jal     showsum

    # get recursive sum (method 2)
    li      $a0,0                   # i = 0
    jal     sumrecurs2              # get recursive sum

    # show the recursive sum results
    la      $a0,msg_recur2
    move    $a1,$v0
    jal     showsum

    # show the difference in values between simple and method 1
    subu    $a1,$s4,$s3             # difference of values
    la      $a0,msg_match
    jal     showsum

    # exit the program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# sumsimple -- compute simple sum by looping through array
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- sum
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- array count
#   t1 -- array pointer
sumsimple:
    move    $t0,$s0                 # get array count
    move    $t1,$s1                 # get array address

    li      $v0,0                   # sum = 0
    j       sumsimple_test

sumsimple_loop:
    lw      $t2,0($t1)              # get array[i]
    add     $v0,$v0,$t2             # sum += array[i]

    addi    $t1,$t1,4               # advance pointer to array[i + 1]
    subi    $t0,$t0,1               # decrement count

sumsimple_test:
    bgtz    $t0,sumsimple_loop      # are we done? if no, loop

    jr      $ra                     # return

# sumrecurs1 -- compute recursive sum
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- sum
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- array index (i)
#   s1 -- array pointer
#
# NOTES:
# (1) in the mips ABI, the second argument is normally passed in a1 [which can
#     be trashed] but we are using s1 as a "global" register
# (2) this saves an extra [and unnecessary push/pop to stack] as s1 _must_ be
#     preserved
# (3) we do, however, preserve the array index (a0) on the stack
sumrecurs1:
    # save return address and argument on a stack frame we setup
    subiu   $sp,$sp,8
    sw      $ra,0($sp)
    sw      $a0,4($sp)

    blt     $a0,$s2,sumrecurs1_call # at the end? if no, fly
    li      $v0,0                   # yes, simulate call return of 0
    j       sumrecurs1_done         # skip to function epilog

sumrecurs1_call:
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # bump up the index
    jal     sumrecurs1              # recursive call

    # get back the index we were called with from our stack frame
    # NOTES:
    # (1) while we _could_ just subtract one from a0 here because of the way
    #     sumrecurs is implemented, we _don't_ because, in general, under the
    #     standard mips ABI the called function is at liberty to _trash_ it
    # (2) the index value restored in the epilog of our recursive function
    #     call is _not_ _our_ value "i", but "i + 1", so we need to get our
    #     "i" value from _our_ stack frame
    # (3) see sumrecurs2 for the faster method where we "cheat" and violate
    #     the ABI
    lw      $a0,4($sp)

sumrecurs1_done:
    sll     $t2,$a0,2               # get byte offset for index i
    add     $t2,$s1,$t2             # get address of array[i]
    lw      $t2,0($t2)              # fetch array[i]
    add     $v0,$t2,$v0             # sum our value and callee's

    # restore return address from stack
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    lw      $a0,4($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,8
    jr      $ra

# sumrecurs2 -- compute recursive sum
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- sum
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- array index (i)
#   s1 -- array pointer
#
# NOTES:
# (1) in the mips ABI, the second argument is normally passed in a1 [which can
#     be trashed] but we are using s1 as a "global" register
# (2) this saves an extra [and unnecessary push/pop to stack] as s1 _must_ be
#     preserved
# (3) we do, however, preserve the array index (a0) on the stack
sumrecurs2:
    # save _only_ return address on a stack frame we setup
    subiu   $sp,$sp,4
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    blt     $a0,$s2,sumrecurs2_call # at the end? if no, fly
    li      $v0,0                   # yes, simulate call return of 0
    j       sumrecurs2_done         # skip to function epilog

sumrecurs2_call:
    addi    $a0,$a0,1               # bump up the index
    jal     sumrecurs2              # recursive call
    subi    $a0,$a0,1               # bump down the index

sumrecurs2_done:
    sll     $t2,$a0,2               # get byte offset for index i
    add     $t2,$s1,$t2             # get address of array[i]
    lw      $t2,0($t2)              # fetch array[i]
    add     $v0,$t2,$v0             # sum our value and callee's

    # restore return address from stack
    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4
    jr      $ra

# showsum -- output a message
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- message
#   a1 -- number value
showsum:
    li      $v0,4                   # puts
    syscall

    move    $a0,$a1                 # get number to print
    li      $v0,1                   # prtint
    syscall

    la      $a0,msg_nl
    li      $v0,4                   # puts
    syscall

    jr      $ra
```